# Using JavaCV with OpenCV gives dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret

Tags: java, maven, opencv, javacv

I am trying to use JavaCV with OpenCV and my maven project dependencies are as below

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0-1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and my Java runtime is 
bash-3.2$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
bash-3.2$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 Jun  7  2015 /usr/bin/java -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

But I keep getting the below error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Users/<workspace>/.javacpp/cache/opencv-3.2.0-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/javacpp/macosx-x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Users/<workspace>/.javacpp/cache/opencv-3.2.0-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/javacpp/macosx-x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: Since openCV uses native libraries, what steps have you followed to install and set it up? Perhaps a link that can help: https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#set-up-opencv-for-java-in-eclipse

Comment: I tried the same but did not help but found from the article below that    The library in question (libSystem.B.dylib) is a system library which exists on that machine. After some research I found out that the symbol sincos_stret is a function that is only exposed after mac osx 10.9, so that is probably why it does not find it on 10.8.How do we get  OpenCV working on 10.8.3 version of mac ?                     http://answers.opencv.org/question/129829/where-can-i-find-the-minimum-supported-mac-osx-versions-supported-by-each-version-of-opencv/

Comment: I don't know anything about os x, but I'm guessing if you install earlier version of openCV there might not be this issue no?

Comment: I tried also using homebrew to install opencv manually and the error i get is as below
"
Error: You are using macOS 10.8.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

Error: You are using macOS 10.8.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues."